# Logstash drop filter for event

Tags: logstash

In my log file I have entries like the following:

```
2014-06-25 12:36:18,176 [10] ((null)) INFO  [s=(null)] [u=(null)] Hello from Serilog, running as "David"! [Program] 
2014-06-25 12:36:18,207 [10] ((null)) WARN  [s=(null)] [u=(null)] =======MyOwnLogger====== Hello from log4net, running as David! [MyOwnLogger] 
2014-06-25 12:36:18,209 [10] ((null)) ERROR [s=(null)] [u=(null)] =======MyOwnLogger====== Hello from log4net, running as David! [MyOwnLogger]
```

which are of loglevel INFO, WARN and ERROR respectively.

What I would like to do is to only output to Elasticsearch those entries which are of ERROR level. Here is my Logstash configuration file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "Somepath/*.log"
    }
}

# This filter doesn't work
filter {
  if [loglevel] != "error" { 
    drop { } 
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { host => localhost }
    stdout {}
}
```

Effectively, currently nothing gets sent to Elasticsearch. I know it is related to the filter because if it's not there, all the entries get sent to Elastisearch.

Comment: where's your `grok` filter to parse the records?

Comment: @Alcanzar: As a newbie to all this I was following the instructions on http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/drop. There is a drop filter and I am not trying to use the grok filter. I just don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for grok and figure out a pattern that will match your entries (http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ is a site that can help you test that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this grok filter. It is works at me with your logs

```
filter {
    grok {
            match => ["message","%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} \[%{NUMBER}\] \(\(%{WORD}\)\) %{WORD:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:other}"]
    }

    if [loglevel]!= "ERROR" {
            drop {}
    }
}
```

First, you need to grok the loglevel, then just you can use the field to do if else condition and decide drop or not.