# How to rasie the log level for logs stored in elk stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Is it possible to raise the log level for logs stored on ELK stack? Now I found all log levels are stored on my elk stack, I only want those warning anf error logs are stored in the stack, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the logstash drop filter, which lets you filter out logs based on some criteria, in your case debug, info and the like. From the docs, a filter might look like:

```
filter {
  if [loglevel] == "debug" {
    drop { }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html

Also, your question looks similar to this one:

[Logstash drop filter for event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409119/logstash-drop-filter-for-event)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a log file test.log like below:

```
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,817 | DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java | 86 | Loading bean definitions
WARN | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java | 185 | Loaded 5 bean definitions from location pattern [samContext.xml]
INFO | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java | 323 | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [tmfContext.xml]
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | DefaultDocumentLoader.java | 72 | Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
ERROR | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | BeansDtdResolver.java | 72 | Found beans DTD [http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd] in classpath: spring-beans.dtd
ERROR | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,864 | DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java | 86 | Loading bean definitions
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 411 | Finished creating instance of bean 'MS-SQL'
```

You can define an if conditional on the message you want to keep and drop others:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/your/path/test.log"
        sincedb_path => "/your/path/test.idx"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    if [message] =~ "WARN" or [message] =~ "ERROR" {

    } else {
        drop {}
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug      
    }
}
```

Then, your result will look like:

```
{
       "message" => "WARN | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java | 185 | Loaded 5 bean definitions from location pattern [samContext.xml]",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-09-17T18:30:24.897Z",
          "host" => "MacBook-Pro-de-Alain.local",
          "path" => "/Users/Alain/Workspace/elk/logstash-1.5.4/config/filter/test.log"
}
{
       "message" => "ERROR | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | BeansDtdResolver.java | 72 | Found beans DTD [http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd] in classpath: spring-beans.dtd",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-09-17T18:30:24.898Z",
          "host" => "MacBook-Pro-de-Alain.local",
          "path" => "/Users/Alain/Workspace/elk/logstash-1.5.4/config/filter/test.log"
}
{
       "message" => "ERROR | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,864 | DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java | 86 | Loading bean definitions",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-09-17T18:30:24.899Z",
          "host" => "MacBook-Pro-de-Alain.local",
          "path" => "/Users/Alain/Workspace/elk/logstash-1.5.4/config/filter/test.log"
}
```

Regards,
Alain